# Does it make sense to show the "the questions appears subjective" message on meta for feature requests?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, asking-questions

Does it make sense to report the message about the question being subjective for questions on meta? In particular, does it make sense, when the question is probably a feature request?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, I could have sworn we disabled that for metas. Good catch, making sure that is so.